# Float Values Either Defaulting To 1 or 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to work out something for CellSize in Unity.
This is for the GridLayoutGroup component. I found something that when done with a calculator works perfectly fine: Screen.Width/1280 , Screen.Height/720.
Since I am using 720p as the base resolution and everything looks fine on there I use it as a base. 100x100 looks great for cell size on 720p.

For example their resolution is 1280:1024
It should come out (100, 142) However it always comes out (1.0, 1.0).
If the resolution is tiny... such as 320x200 it comes out (0.0, 0.0).

Here is my code:

```
SlotPanel.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>().cellSize = new Vector2((Cam.pixelWidth / 1280) * 100, (Cam.pixelHeight / 720) * 100);
```

Cam is the Camera that the player uses.
Another code that I tried was:

```
SlotPanel.GetComponenet<GridLayoutGroup>().cellSize = new Vector2((Screen.Width / 1280) * 100, (Screen.Height / 720) * 100);
```

Both result in the same issue. At this point I am at a loss of words for how annoyed I am. I don't understand why the math is right, but it does not work right.

Comment: Try 1280.0, 100.0 instead

Comment: @doctorlove Actually `1280f` (or `1280.0f`) and `720f` (`720.0f`) in this case because you need single-precision for `Vector2` (see first comment to answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cam.pixelWidth / 1280` &c. is evaluated in *integer arithmetic*; any remainder is discarded.

Rewrite to `100.0 * Cam.pixelWidth / 1280` to ensure the evaluation takes place in floating point (due to *promotion* of the two integral arguments). There are other ways, but I find this one to be clearest since changing the first coefficient tells a reader of your code from the get-go what you want to do.

(If you require the type of the expression to be a single precision floating point type then use `100f` in place of `100.0`).

This is one of those cases where using excess parentheses is actually harmful.

Comment: and don't forget the `f` behind 100.0f, as unity uses floats instead of doubles

Comment: I do not agree that excess parentheses are harmful here. They are not related to the problem. But @xyLe_ is right you should not use `100.0` which is a `double`, because then you would have to convert down to `float` (also known as `System.Single`) before you can call the `Vector2` constructor. So you should use `100.0f` or just `100f` in this case. If you want to keep the order of the operations, use `1280f` instead. I see no problem with dividing first, and multiplying by a hundred afterwards.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I've added the `100f` case. I suffer the scarring from a 3am debugging session where some flashy quant had introduced some parentheses into an expression which grouped integral types. Sadly it was in a "change of measure" term so the effect of that being zero was not immediately noticeable. There is no substitute for **learning your operator precedence table**.

Comment: The original question had `(Cam.pixelWidth / 1280) * 100` as the expression. Then the division is "first". You correctly explained that this is an integer division, i.e. goes to the C# pre-defined overload `int static operator /(int, int)` which returns `int`, and as you said, the remainder is thrown away. Had the asker dropped the parenthesis, he would have `Cam.pixelWidth / 1280 * 100`. This is a bit harder to read for a human mathematician. However, we both agree the meaning in C# is exactly the same. Again the division `/` "comes first" (because of left associativity this time).

Comment: ... Therefore I tend to conclude that the excess parenthesis was not harmful. The problem was unrelated to the parenthesis. The excess parenthesis seems innocent to me; it can help a human reader that might want to be sure the order was in fact intentional. I am not saying I _recommend_ redundant parentheses, I am just suggesting they are harmless.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me find an answer to this. I am glad to find out why it did not work instead of just getting a quick fix. I will read over all this information carefully and try my best to remember it all in future instances.

I love how quick this community is to respond. Much faster than the actual Unity forums. I sat there for 5 days with this question without a response. Thank you all once again for the fast response times :D